# Samba guest ok = no doest appear in testparm -s

Tags: samba, file-sharing

If I set guest ok = no in samba configuation file, when running `testparm -s`, it does not appear on the that file. After changing the samba.conf file I saved it and restart the samba file and then run the `testparm -s`.

I've configured Samba as follows:

[image: Samba config file]

After running `testparm -s`:

[image: Testparm image]

Answer (score 0):

smb.conf despite it's name is not THE configuration file for samba. It's a file that can be used to change default settings or add new ones to the default configuration that runs by default.

When the system initiates the samba service it looks to smb.conf for those differences and applies them to the default. testparm is doing the same interpretation of your smb.conf file.

The reason `guest ok = no` does not show up is because it is in fact the [global] default setting for samba. You can't see the defaults directly but you can see the defaults by running testparm in a particular way and pointing to an empty smb.conf file:

testparm -sv /dev/null | grep 'guest ok'

Like this:

```
~$ testparm -sv /dev/null | grep 'guest ok'
Load smb config files from /dev/null
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

    guest ok = No
```

testparm will only show the changes that would be made by your smb.conf to the default settings and your manual entry is redundant.